# Can I use GPIO logic level converters as tiny low-current solid state relays?

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, gpio, solid-state-relay, logic-level

In order to use a GPIO pin to drive a 180 mA mini water pump, the GPIO pin needs to switch a MOSFET or an Optocoupler because it can't safely do 180 mA.

I want to run 16 low-current pumps from 16 GPIO pins. I'll only be running one pump at a time, because the pumps will be powered by the same Li-ion battery as the GPIO device.

Can I use one of those 4- or 8-channel 3.3 V to 5 V logic level converters as mini relays? They are quite cheap and easy to handle. They are made by [Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/757), [SparkFun](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12009), and there are even 8 channel ones such as [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01CZVZ3US) and [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B088TSY1MN). The only problem is that I'll be using the same voltage for the high and the low side.

Alternatively I can use a [dedicated solid state relay boards](https://www.sainsmart.com/products/2-4-8-ch-5v-solid-state-relay), but those are very heavy-duty and I prefer something lightweight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a bidirectional logic level converter has no current gain, so it won't serve your purpose. However, you could use a Darlington transistor array, such as the ULN200x series.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. Can you elaborate a little bit? The [ULN2001](https://html.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf/25574/STMICROELECTRONICS/ULN2001/1621/1/ULN2001.html) has IN, OUT, and GND. Where does the extra current come from if I can't attach VCC?

Comment: The positive side of each pump connects directly to the power supply. Pin 9 should also be connected to that power supply so that the diodes can protect the transistors.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't use these level shifters to drive a 180mA pump even if you manage them to put in right configuration. The shifters, per descriptions, use [BSS138](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/BSS138.pdf) N-FETs. The FETs have 6 Ohm Rds_on even if driven by 4.5V. As such the transistor will dissipate about 200mW, and the tiny SOT-23 case will likely overheat and burn out.

[image]

You will need to use a beefier MOSFETS, or see Dave's recommendation regarding the use of ULN2001 IC, it even has all necessary clamping diodes.

Comment: I have tested using 3.3V on a bread board and everything works as expected. The 180 mA pump runs for five minutes and the BSS138 doesn't even get noticeably warm. But here's the real puzzle: Once I attach the logic VIN to GPIO in stead 3.3V, it doesn't work anymore. My oscillator shows it turns on for 10 milliseconds and then off again. I can tell the pin is working properly because I can replace the BSS138 with a LED + resistor and then it works. I don't understand what causes the problem, but clearly this won't work. Albeit for different reasons than expected.